# DOMDocument saveHTML is not returning correct HTML Standards for "IMG", "INPUT"

Tags: html, simplexml, domdocument, w3c-validation, phpquery

I'm a big fan of the PHP library [phpQuery](https://github.com/punkave/phpQuery) content parser (because its quite like **jQuery**, while using the [PHP DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) to extract Markup) but I've noticed a bug with specific elements with the *quick closing event* `<img />` instead of `<div></div>`

I've noticed this bug also occurs in `DOMDocument` as  well as `phpQuery`.

I've written a simple class [PhpContentDocument](https://pastebin.com/fHzSwhe3) to dump a simple html document.

```
require_once "../phpquery_lib/phpQuery.php";
require_once "PhpContentDocument.class.php";

$sample_document = new PhpContentDocument('Sample Document');
$sample_document->addElement('text element', "<span class='text_element'>This is some Sample Text</span>");
$sample_document->addElement('image element', "<img src='png_file.png' alt='png_file' id='png_file' />");

$sample_document_string = $sample_document->get_string();
```

The results are what you would expect ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>Sample Document</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8" />
<body>
<span class='text_element'>This is some Sample Text</span>
<img src='png_file.png' alt='png_file' id='png_file' />
</body>
</html>
```

But when recalling the document using saveHTML

```
$php_query_document = new DOMDocument('UTF-8', '1.0');
$php_query_document->formatOutput = true;
$php_query_document->preserveWhiteSpace = true;
$php_query_document->loadHTML($sample_document_string);

$php_query_document_string = $php_query_document->saveHTML();

echo $php_query_document_string;
```

it returns ...

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
<title>Sample Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<span class="text_element">This is some Sample Text</span>
<img src="png_file.png" alt="png_file" id="png_file">
</body>
</html>
```

The main problem I have with this, is when I use [SimpleXMLElement](http://php.net/manual/en/class.simplexmlelement.php) on the element `img#png_file` *(for example)*

**Using content parser** passing `<img src="png_file.png" alt="png_file" id="png_file">` as the argument

```
$simple_doc = new SimpleXMLElement((string) $php_query_document->find('img#png_file'));
```

I get the following warnings and exceptions, even though my original markup would work with the `SimpleXMLElement`.

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag img line 1 in F:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Code\phpquery_test_items\index.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): <img src="png_file.png" alt="png_file" id="png_file"> in F:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Code\phpquery_test_items\index.php on line 17

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): ^ in F:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Code\phpquery_test_items\index.php on line 17

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'String could not be parsed as XML' in F:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Code\phpquery_test_items\index.php:17 Stack trace: #0 F:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Code\phpquery_test_items\index.php(17): SimpleXMLElement->__construct('<img src="png_f...') #1 {main} thrown in F:\xampp\htdocs\Test_Code\phpquery_test_items\index.php on line 17
```

Due to the element having no `closing event`.

TL:DR `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct(): Entity: line 1: parser error : Premature end of data in tag img line 1`

How can I fix this? I do have some ideas but preferably

- I want a solution where I can use regex (where I know the ELEMENT TYPE) in order to replace `/>` with `<{element_type}/>`, and vice versa.
- `DOMDocument` class with `saveHTML` fixed (maybe a class that extends `DOMDocument` in order to inherit other functionality).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`DOMDocument::saveXML()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savexml.php) instead of [`DOMDocument::saveHTML()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/domdocument.savehtml.php) you'll get valid XML.

If necessary you could then strip the xml declaration line `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`.

---

I just realized you want the `find()` method to return the proper XML. Therefore I'm not sure my above-mentioned suggestion is all that helpful, if it means you have to alter the class that implements that method.

Perhaps you could do something a little convoluted like:

```
$node = $php_query_document->find('img#png_file');
$simple_doc = new SimpleXMLElement( $node->ownerDocument->saveXML( $node ) );
```

This presupposes `$node` is some implementation of [`DOMNode`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php), which I suspect it is. What this does is ask the `$node->ownerDocument` (the [`DOMDocument`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) that contains the node) to save only that specific node as XML.

---

Another possibility (which I would not necessarily recommend) is to let `SimpleXML` be lenient, when parsing, by passing the following libxml options to the constructor:

```
$simple_doc = new SimpleXMLElement(
    (string) $php_query_document->find('img#png_file'), 
    LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_ERR_NONE | LIBXML_ERR_FATAL
);
```

This suppresses libxml errors while parsing the content. [libxml](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/book.libxml.php) is the underlying XML parser, used by SimpleXML and DOMDocument (amongst others).

Comment: Do you have regular expression to find words #[0-9]; for example #13; ? Because saveXML inserts these random character references

Comment: @Killrawr I don't think you are using `SimpleXML` properly, because what you are referring to is the output of doing a `var_dump()`, I believe. What are you trying to achieve with `SimpleXML`? Please edit your question (or preferably start a new question) with the new issue you are facing. If you still need help with regular expressions, please also start a completely new question about the regular expression issue.